# Power Query: Build Date out of Text

Tags: excel, powerquery

our Ticketsystem gives me nice reports, unfortunately they are stupidly formatted.
in a monthly overview, I get the date column as:

```
Mon 1 
Tue 2 
Wed 3 
... 
Sat 31
```

I'd like to build a proper date out of this nonses.
My Idea is to:

1. Split the column by delimiter (first space from left) giving me Columns Date.1 and Date.2
2. Concatenate Date.2 & "." & "current month - 1" & "." & "current year"
3. Format this as date

Is this correct so far? If so: 
I know how to get e.g. the month out of a date, but how do I get "currentmonth - 1" (i.e. the last month number) and current year?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date, then add a custom column with `Date.AddMonths`. If your date column is in `[Date]`, then the custom formula you want to add is `Date.AddMonths([Date], -1)`.

If you want the current year (local), you can use `Date.Year(DateTime.FixedLocalNow))`. Building a date from this is problematic, however, because the table will change based on when you view the report.

Comment: Great. I'm able to get the current year with Date.Year(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()), but how do I get the last month (current month -1) as fixed?

Comment: using Date.AddMonths(Date.Month(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()), -1) retunrs an error

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
Date.Month(Date.AddMonths(DateTime.FixedLocalNow(), -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like that:

```
    SplitTable = //split that date
    Now = DateTime.FixedLocalNow(),
//then
    NewCol = Table.AddColumns(SplitDate, "NewDate", 
              each #date(Date.Year(Date.AddMonths(Now, -1)), Date.Month(Date.AddMonths(Now, -1)), [Date.2]  ),
//etc.
```

But also you have to add checks if [Date.2] day exists in prev. month, since e.g. in march you'll get errors for days later than 28/29.